# Euclidean embeddings of cayley graphs

Tags: group-theory, geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, geometric-group-theory

For any finite group $G$, we can define a 'dimension' of the group as the smallest $n$ such that there is some choice of generators $S$ of $G$ where $G$ equipped with word metric with respect to $S$ is isometrically embeddable into euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Equivalently, this means the cayley graph on $G$ (equipped with shortest-path-length metric) with edges labelled by elements in $S$ and edge-lengths $1$ is isometrically embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is a finite number, since taking $S = G$ you get the discrete metric, which is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^{|G|-1}$ as a simplex.

- Is there a name for this 'dimension'? I'm not having any luck with google searches.
- I'd be interested to know bounds on this dimension (assuming it is studied as is nontrivial) for the finite simple groups

Comment: Finite graphs cannot embed isometrically into $\Bbb R^5$?

Comment: Think about the cyclic group of order 4 with one generator.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: That graph has dim.infty? But the dimension of the full graph is what?

Comment: @markvs: Of course 3.

Comment: Then the dim of every finite group is $3$?

Comment: I see, I misread the question.

Comment: I doubt there is much research about this. It looks nasty. For example what is the dimension of $C_3 \times C_3$?